# Store code line in a string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to store code in a string so that if a value is true, it is in the code line if not true its not in the code line. When I populate summarytextbox if consulting amount is "" then dont use this code if is does have an amount include the code. Is this possible? Other wise I would have to do a bunch if then statements. When I do the following below it cant convert to double.

```
Dim ConsultingFee As String 
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("ConsultingFeeAmount") = "" Then

    Else
'Store the following line in a string????
        ConsultingFee = +Environment.NewLine + Session("ConsultingFee") + " Amount: " + Session("ConsultingFeeAmount")

    End If



    SummaryTextBox.Text = Session("TeachingHospital") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalAddress") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalCity") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalState") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalZip") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalTIN") + ConsultingFee

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is your question, how to cast values in `Session` to the correct .NET type? Everything in `Session` is an `object`.

Comment: No, How do I store the code Environment.NewLine + Session("ConsultingFee") + " Amount: " + Session("ConsultingFeeAmount") into a variable or string? Because I wont always need this code in my summarytextbox.text

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing in the line right after the comment `'Store the following line in a string????`? I am not sure about your syntax there, it has been a few years since I have done VB.NET, but I am pretty sure `ConsultingFee = +Environment.NewLine` is not legal syntax. I think you mean `ConsultingFee = ConsultingFee + Environment.NewLine`, right? Or you can use the `+=` syntax as well.

Comment: Great, I have posted the answer below just for clarification if someone else comes upon this question and does not want to read through the comments to decipher. Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate onto the `ConsultingFee` string variable, like this:

```
ConsultingFee = ConsultingFee & Environment.NewLine & Session("ConsultingFee") & " Amount: " & Session("ConsultingFeeAmount")
```

OR

```
ConsultingFee &= Environment.NewLine & Session("ConsultingFee") & " Amount: " + Session("ConsultingFeeAmount")
```

Comment: String concatenation in VB is the & operator (or &=).  The + operator will work in most cases, but it potentially give unexpected results (like an InvalidCastException).  It is recommended to use the & operator in VB.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - thank you kind sir, it has been many moons since programming in VB.NET, but as soon as I saw your comment I recall the distinction.